# $ctrl in data binding is not working

Tags: angularjs, json, data-binding

I want to make a dynamic page using angular where the user after  he logged-in see his user picture and some information charged by json file throught an http request.
This is the module where i do the http requestes:

```
         'user strict';

angular.
 module('userIssue').
 component('userIssue',{
    templateUrl: 'user-issue/user-issue.html',
    controller: 'userIssueCtrl'
 })

.controller('userIssueCtrl',['$scope','$http','$routeParams',function       userIssueCtrl($scope,$http,$routeParams){
var self = this;
var percorso;
$scope.utente=$routeParams.username;
document.title="Benvenuto"+" "+$routeParams.username;



$http.get('user/'+ $routeParams.username+'.json').then(function(response){
  self.utenti = response.data;

});

$http.get('user/'+$routeParams.username+'.info.json').then(function(qualcosa){
  self.d = qualcosa.data;
});

self.show = function(){
  $scope.showForm='false';
}

}]);
```

and this is the part of the html page not working:

```
 <div class="col-sm-4">  
 <img  style="position:center;" ng-src="{{$ctrl.d.imgUrl}}" class="img-circle" alt="user image"></div>
```

I'm using the same approch in this part of the code:

```
<div  class="col-md-9 col-sm-9" id="issueColumn" >
<div id="issue" ng-repeat='utenti in $ctrl.utenti'>
               <li>
<dt>CODICE OPERAZIONE</dt>
<dd>{{utenti.id}}</dd>
<dt>DESCRIZIONE PROBLEMA</dt>
<dd>{{utenti.description}}</dd>
<dt>DATA SEGNALAZIONE</dt>
<dd>{{utenti.forward}}</dd>
<dt>IL PROBLEMA SARà RISOLTO ENTRO IL:</dt>
<dd>{{utenti.endstimed}}</dd>
<dt>STATO DEL PROBLEMA:</dt>
<dd>{{utenti.stato}}</dd>
</li> </br>
</div>
</div>
```

and here it is working! So why does the data binding not work for the image?
Could someone gently explain me why?

Here is the json file I use for the image:

```
   [
 {
   "imgUrl": "img/Filippo.png",
   "ciao": "ciao_calro"
 }
   ]
```

Comment: show the full json

Comment: this is my full json, it is little because it's just for a trial. Obviously i can put the one that is working but i don't want to confuse people

Comment: you need to access the first element of the json `ng-src="{{$ctrl.d[0].imgUrl}}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to use 1st element of `d` array object, you should be accessing 1st element of `imgUrl` property explicitly.

```
ng-src="{{$ctrl.d[0].imgUrl}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you try the below changes from your code and let me know,

1. Introduced controllerAs with the controller object:

> component('userIssue',{
>       templateUrl: 'user-issue/user-issue.html',
>       **controllerAs: 'userCtrl'**
>       controller: 'userIssueCtrl'  })

2. Accessing through the controller object name:

Try to access through the controller object name like,

{{**userCtrl.d.imgUrl**}} in template.